# Replace two or three parts of a URL in a JavaScript bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, url, bookmarklet

### Original URL

https://website.org/**directory/page**­*.php*

### Updated URL

https://sub1.sub2.site.com/files/content?site=mysite&path=/**directory/page**­*.html*

I already have this great bookmarklet for switching the subdomain from a production server to development.

`javascript:location.href=location.protocol+"//"+"webproto"+"."+(location.host.split(".").length==3?location.host.split(".").slice(1,location.host.split(".").length).join("."):location.host)+location.pathname+location.search;`

But I cannot figure out how to take this to the next level by

1. replacing the subdomain with multiple subdomains
2. replacing the domain name extension
3. adding the path with query and params
4. and switching the extension

Comment: I'm assuming that `site=mysite` in the "updated Url" should actually be `site=website.org`?

Comment: No. I actually want to switch the `.org` to `.com` as well. I accidentally left off the word "extension" on bullet #2. Sorry about that I have my question updated.

Comment: to change the top level domain from org to com, you could use the same pattern i use to change the extension of the file.

Comment: in your output: `&path=/directory/page­.html` is not url encoded.  in my output it's `path=%2Fdirectory%2Fpage.html` since the url-parse library is properly url encoding the query string parts...+1 for using a lib ;)

Answer (score 0):

So putting this into a bookmarklet while making it robust is non trivial.  Here's my solution.

1. install webpack with `npm install -g webpack`
2. create a file layout like this:

---

```
project/
  bookmarklet.js
  download/
     urlMunge.js
```

---

3. The contents of bookmarklet.js

---

```
javascript: (function () {
   var jsCode = document.createElement('script');
   jsCode.setAttribute('src', 'https://YOUR_SERVER/bundle.js');
   document.body.appendChild(jsCode);
}());
```

---

4. the contents of `urlMunge.js`

---

```
// put all in a function to make sure that we don't mess up whatever page
// we are on.
var urlMunge = function urlMunge() {
  var URL = require('url-parse');
  var EXT = '.html';

  // https://sub1.sub2.site.com/files/content?site=mysite&path=/directory/page.html
  test1 = window.location;
  var sourceUrl = new URL(test1);
  var formattedUrl = new URL('https://sub1.sub2.site.com/files/content');
  var pathname = sourceUrl.pathname;
  var host = sourceUrl.host;
  var query = {
    query: sourceUrl.query,
    path: pathname.slice(0, pathname.lastIndexOf('.')) + EXT,
    host: host.slice(0, host.lastIndexOf('.')) + '.com',
  }

  formattedUrl.set('query', query);

  console.log(formattedUrl.toString());
}

urlMunge();
```

---

5. add the url-parse library.  `cd` into the download directory and run `npm install url-parse` which will create a `node_modules` directory with url-parse and its dependencies.
6. in the download directory run `webpack urlMunge.js ../bundle.js` which will create bundle.js with both our code and the url-parse lib.
7. place bundle.js into a webserver where your bookmarklet can load it and test away.  You'll need to look in the console of your browser to see the output of urlMunge.

Comment: oops.  my bad. here's a great primer on bookmarkelts: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-bookmarklets-the-right-way--net-18154  I think that the best advice is to externalize your script so you can continue to develop it over time without depending on your users re-installing.  So my solution would be a script that is called by the book marklet.  I'll try and wrap it all up with a bow  this afternoon.

Comment: What a robust answer! +1 for nmp. I've never heard of urlMunge and can't wait to run through this, hopefully tomorrow.